# Redis sorted set for post-vote and user-reputation

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I use Stackexchange.Redis in c# . How StackOverflow use sorted set to calculate the post-vote and user-reputation in [Redis](http://redis.io/). How to use [ZADD](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) ,[ZUNIONSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/zunionstore) or [ZINTERSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore) . How to use `[WEIGHTS weight [weight ...]] [AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX]` parameter to calculate the post-vote and user-reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How StackOverflow use sorted set to calculate the post-vote and user-reputation in Redis.

we don't, although it is on my list to look at

> How to use ZADD ,ZUNIONSTORE or ZINTERSTORE .

`SortedSetAdd` and `SortedSetCombineAndStore`

> How to use [WEIGHTS weight [weight ...]] [AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX] parameter

The `SortedSetCombineAndStore` overload including the `weights` and `aggregate` parameters

> to calculate the post-vote and user-reputation.

I can only tell you what the commands are. How you use them in your case is up to you. Personally, I'd be looking more at `SortedSetRangeByRankWithScores`.

Comment: So, what dose stackoverflow? Use sql query in sqlserver or may be use `INCR` or `DECR`key in Redis for calculate vote and reputation

Comment: @Amir at the moment, SQL server and some scheduled calculations to populate some numbers. But soon: redis sorted sets.